# how to checkout specific tag/commit (git) with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, tags, jenkins-pipeline, git-checkout

till now I ran the follwoing command in jenkins:

```
git branch: branch_nam, url: url, credentialsId: cred
```

and it works fine.
I've tried to add a way to checkout specific tag/commit so I've used the follwing command:

```
checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: url]], branches: [[name: tag]]], credentialsId: cred, poll: false
```

but I get the following error:

> ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress
>   http://codefront:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/some_folder
>   +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for
>   http://codefront:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/some_folder

what did I do wrong?
what is the difference between they way each command works?

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems like the problem is with the tag I gave. when I use commit ID it works fine. I gave as tag: ref/tags/mytag

Comment: checkout scm is a more generic way (you can than use other source control systems, depends on the $class you choose).  I did used git and than moved to checkout scm. It really depends on the Job Type you are using (Pipeline, Multi branch Pipeline,  Github Organization, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

refer to the doc here : https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

[image: jenkins user remote configs param manual]

check if your url respect it. Please give me the value if it isn't the problem.

Comment: I run: git rev-parse --is-bare-repository, and got false.

Comment: I just see your comment on your post. did you try just the tag name without ref/tags ?

Comment: my bad, seems it did not really worked (I though I run with specific commit but apparently not)... so it seems to be the checkout command compare to branch command. I read about problems with GIT_ASKPASS but still could not find a solution

Comment: ok just try to run a shell command with : sh 'git checkout <tagName>' don't write ref/tags, juste the tag name.

Comment: do I have a way to run corss platform shell?

Comment: no, write this line in your jenkinsfile instead of "checkout scm..."